# error in servalet java

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

i am beginner to servlet ... i want to pass a simple parameter from html to servlet but an error "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" applears .. here it is my code ...
web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewClass</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>NewClass</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewClass</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewClass</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>newhtml.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

newhtml.xml

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Application</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/NewClass" >
            <input name="username" />
            <input type="submit"/>
                
        </form>
    </body>
</html><html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Application</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/NewClass" >
            <input name="username" />
            <input type="submit"/>
                
        </form>
    </body>
</html><html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Application</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/NewClass" >
            <input name="username" />
            <input type="submit"/>
                
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

NewClass.java

```html
public class NewClass extends HttpServlet{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String req = request.getParameter("username");
        out.println(req);}}
```

please anyone tell me why is an error is appearing to me ??

Comment: How did you deploy your webapp to tomcat, what is the name of your webapp?

Comment: You might not be connecting to the server. If launching outside of an IDE, make sure you start up the server. Also, make sure you type in the correct addresss, `http://localhost:8080/`. If you are doing some tutorial then just make sure you follow every step to the letter.

Comment: He did get a 404, that is somewhat hard without a server :P

Comment: Make sure the server is running first and also give the qualified name of the class in web.xml

Comment: Suppose I still need to wake up... OP, ensure your file structure is set up correctly, such as placing your project in Catalina home. Also, iirc there should be some info on the default error page on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your `<form action=""/>`
It must be

```
 <form action="NewClass" >
        <input name="username" />
        <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

When you put the `/` in your action tag it points the root instead of pointing the context path.